# Vue v-for update SO SLOW

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I use Vue (latest) to render a page of selections. Components have to communicate, so I use vuex as well. In Vuex:

```
Vue.use(Vuex); //Use the Vuex state manager
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cparr: [],
    current_entry: {},
  },
  mutations: {
    clearAllPoints: function(state) {
      console.log("Removing ALL Points");
      state.cparr = [];
      console.log("FINISHED Removing ALL Points");
    },
  },
});
```

A user selects regions, each region can have several hundred points, the selected regions show their selected points in another div/component. No problem.

The user can "Clear all points". That uses vuex to set "`state.cparr = [];`"

This is rendered through a "computed" function/method:

```
  computed: {
    points: function() {
      return this.$store.state.cparr;
    },
  },
```

... and this all worked great, instantly, until a few days ago, when I made some totally unrelated changes.

And it still works. Only now it takes literally 2-3 minutes to render the change.

I've tried "this.$forceUpdate()". I added logging to the method:

```
clearAllPoints: function() {
  console.log("Start force update clearAllPoints");
  this.$store.commit('clearAllPoints');
  this.$forceUpdate();
  console.log("FINISH force update clearAllPoints");
},
```

The console log messages appear immediately. No error reports. Nothing happens, until 2 minutes, then the points disappear.

I tried adding :key & :id in the template:

```
    <table class="selected-points-table">
      <tr><th>Module Name</th><th>Case Name</th><th>Point Name</th>
        <th @click="clearAllPoints" title="Remove all selected points" class="pseudo-link">Remove All</th></tr>
        <tr v-for="(point, 

pdx) in points" :key="point.point_guid" :id="'point-id-'+point.point_guid">
```

... and no change in the 2 minute re-rendering time of NOTHING.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong, or any diagnostic suggestion?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: `$forceUpdate()` shouldn't be required. can you use Chrome Vue dev tools to check if the computed value `points` is still updating immediately after `cparr` changes? a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be great.

Comment: Still don't have the solution, but as I dig deeper, I see an awful lot of time is spent in the babel polyfill, which is probably because I added more ES6/7 features to the code. Which would explain why it's slower now than earlier versions. I'm still trying to figure out how to transpile as much as possible & rely on browser runtime polyfills as little as possible, but my insight into the subtleties webpack & babel is quite limited.

Comment: Oh, and if I output to console, the array is reset to empty almost immediately. I added a "nextTick" callback which also logs to console. After the 2 minutes, when the array / list is actually removed from the visual dom, the nextTick callback fires at the same time.